# java android error Cannot resolve method 'shutdown' in 'DevicePolicyManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola tengo el siguente codigo donde estoy tratando de usar el metodo shutdown para apagar un dispositivo android desde java pero al momento de usar el metodo shutdown me dice lo siguiente:
Cannot resolve method 'shutdown' in 'DevicePolicyManager' en android estudio, no encuento la manera de apagar el dispositivo:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText passwordEditText;
private Button shutdownButton;
private DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
private ComponentName componentName;
private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password_edit_text);
    shutdownButton = findViewById(R.id.shutdown_button);

    // Initialize device policy manager and component name
    devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    componentName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminReceiver.class);

    shutdownButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

            // Check if the password is correct
            if (password.equals("mypassword")) {
                // Request admin permission to shutdown the device
                PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
                powerManager.reboot(null);
                devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
                devicePolicyManager.shutdown(componentName);
                if (devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName)) {

                   //devicePolicyManager.reboot(componentName);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Request admin permission
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Please activate device admin");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que no puede encontrar el método `shutdown` de la clase [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager), si revisas la documentación de la clase [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager), este método en realidad no existe, debes eliminarlo.

Incluso tienes un problema en el código, ya que `devicePolicyManager.lockNow()` debe ser llamado solo cuando se determina que el componente es activo `devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive()`, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
            ...
            ... 
            //devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
            //devicePolicyManager.shutdown(componentName);
            if (devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName)) {

               devicePolicyManager.lockNow();

               //devicePolicyManager.reboot(componentName);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Is Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Request admin permission
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Please activate device admin");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
            ...
            ...
```